# Error using function pointer as default argument to template method

Tags: c++, templates, namespaces, function-pointers, default-arguments

When I try to compile this code, I get the following compiler error in Visual Studio 2012:

```
error C2440: 'default argument' : cannot convert 'void(_cdecl*)(void)' to 'void(_cdecl*)(void)'
```

My code:

```
namespace bar {
    template<typename T> void foo();
    template<> void foo<int>() {}
}

struct A {
    void(*f)();

    template<typename T> inline void set_func(void(*f)()=bar::foo<T>) {this->f=f;}
};

int main(void) {
    A a;
    a.set_func<int>();
    return 0;
}
```

When I move `bar::foo` into the global namespace, I don't get the error anymore. Can anyone please explain?

I've edited the above code to remove some confusion about member functions and template specialization. I also removed the typedef, which gives an even weirder version of the same error : `cannot convert 'void(_cdecl*)(void)' to 'void(_cdecl*)(void)'`

Comment: Your compiler is broken. Maybe using `&bar::foo<T>` could help because it removes the implicit conversion to a function pointer.

Comment: changing `bar::foo<T>` to `&bar::foo<T>` didn't work

Comment: Does the error message say more about why the conversion cannot happen? Can you remove the typedef and just specify the type directly? Have you filed a bug report on MS Connect?

Comment: removing the typedef and using `void(*)()` directly does not help. I will file a bug report to MS, as this seems to be unusual.

Comment: I don't know if this is related, but you're making an explicit  specialization of `bar::foo` and this should be done in the same namespace, e.g. `namespace bar{template<> void foo<int>() {}}` (because of the `bar::foo` syntax, I initially thought that `bar` was a class, hence the answer that I deleted).

Comment: removing the explicit specialization has no impact on the result :(

Comment: Try to add `template` keyword to this code: `func_fn f=bar::template foo<T>`. And put explicit specialization to namespace `bar`. Also at least the declaration of specialization should be visible at the point of `set_func` function template definition.

Comment: nope, `func_fn f=bar::template foo<T>` doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because this is quite obviously a bug in the compiler itself, all I can do is create a workaround to achieve the same effect.

I removed the default arguments and used an overloaded method as follows:

```
template<typename T> inline void set_func() {this->f=bar::foo<T>;}
template<typename T> inline void set_func(void(*f)()) {this->f=f;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another work around for this problem.

```
typedef void (*FunctionPointer)(int, int);

class Template
{
    public:
        template<typename Type>
        static void Function(int Arg0, int Arg1)
        {
            // Code and Stuff
        }

        // ORIGINAL FUNCTION - Produces compile errors.
        // Produces - error C2440: 'default argument' : cannot convert from 'overloaded-function' to 'FunctionPointer' (VS2012 SP5 x64)
        template<typename Type>    
        void Original(FunctionPointer Arg = &Template::Function<Type>)
        {
            // Code and Stuff
        }

        // WORKAROUND FUNCTION - Compiles fine.
        // Default Arg parameter to NULL and initialize default parameter inside function on runtime.
        template<typename Type>    
        void Original(FunctionPointer Arg = NULL)
        {
            if (Arg == NULL)
                Arg = &Template::Function<Type>;

            // Code and Stuff
        }
}
```